# Extract Text Box Off of Shape in Powerpoint Using Apache POI XSLF

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

I am using Java and the Apache POI library to parse a powerpoint slide.  I can extract the shapes and connectors, but I am having difficulty extracting the "text" that is sitting within each shape.  Here is sample code that gets the shape and this is working fine.

```
           XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(file));
            List<XSLFSlide> slide = ppt.getSlides();
            System.out.println("These are the shapes in the presentation: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < slide.size(); i++) {
                List<XSLFShape> listOfShapes = slide.get(i).getShapes();
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfShapes.size(); j++) {
                    XSLFShape thisShape = listOfShapes.get(j);
                    String thisShapeName = thisShape.getShapeName();
                    int thisShapeID = thisShape.getShapeId();
                    XSLFShapeContainer thisShapeParent = thisShape.getParent();
                    Rectangle2D thisAnchor = thisShape.getAnchor();
                    String textBody = thisShape.;
                    System.out.println("Name: " + thisShapeName + " ID: " + thisShapeID + " Anchor: " + thisAnchor.toString());
                }
            }
```

I thought, based on what I read about the XSLFTextShape class and elsewhere that I could get the text on each shape by simply saying:

```
String textOnShape = thisShape.getTextBody();
```

But getTextBody does not appear to be an acceptable method.  I have read the question and answer to this same question using Apache POI HSLF, but I am using XSLF (the newer version).  I am missing something obvious with the syntax, but if anyone has done this before and has a thought it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out.  When you are iterating through you need to recast the shape object a couple of times as follows:

```
XSLFShape thisShape = listOfShapes.get(j);
XSLFSimpleShape thisSimpleShape = (XSLFSimpleShape) thisShape;
XSLFTextShape thisTextShape = (XSLFTextShape) thisSimpleShape;
System.out.println(thisTextShape.getText());
```

That will get you the text sitting on the shape itself.